How do I mock a custom hook with axios for testing?
I have a custom hook which fetches data from a third party api. I need to create a test using vitest but I can't seem to find anything that works.
If any one is able to help that would be much appreciated. I've included the hook below.
This is how the hook is called...
const { data, error, loading } = useFetch({ url: 'https://api.some_url.com/search?q=', query: 'some search term' });

This is the useFetch custom hook...
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type FetchParams = {
  url: string;
  query: string;
};

export function useFetch(props: FetchParams) {
  const { url, query } = props;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUrl: string = `${url}${query}`;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      await fetch(fetchUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          setLoading(false);
          setData(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setLoading(false);
          setError(error);
        });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url, query]);

  return { data, error, loading };
}



There are lots of libraries for mocking axios out there. This is how you'd do it without using any of them ;)
import * as axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

it('test success', () => {
    axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { ... } }));

    // actual test
});

Errors are testable in a similar way, you'd just want to mock-return a Promise.reject.
